# OnClick event not firing on ModalDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Modal Dialog:

```
function ShowPopup() 
{
  window.showModalDialog('dialog.aspx',    null, 'status:no;dialogWidth:950px;dialogHeight:150 px');
}
```

Then its called in the code behind

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popUpScript", "ShowPopup();", true);
```

The dialog.aspx has two buttons:

```
<asp:Button id="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" OnClick="btn1_Click"></asp:Button>
<asp:Button id="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" OnClick="btn2_Click"></asp:Button>
```

However, the Click events in the code behind are never getting fired.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(url)
    }

    protected void btn2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall seeing this problem before and I think it is related to caching. Try adding this to your dialog.aspx page_load method when  !IsPostBack

```
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
```

To stop the browser caching the page and reusing it

Comment: No luck. Still never even hitting the event on button click.

Comment: Does it even hit page_load? Like suggested by rick make sure there is no js error. Make sure your aspx has AutoEventWireup="true" for the page element. Also double check and make sure you dont have multiple copies of dialog.aspx and the wrong file was loaded

Comment: AutoEventWireup is set to true on the .aspx - as far as I can tell there are no js errors. I did take a quick look to see if I had an older version of the dialog.aspx being loaded, but I do not.

Comment: And yes, the page_load fires. If I call the click event from the page load, everything works. It's just not firing when actually clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any hidden JavaScript errors preventing the POST?